# Can't make two different pop up with leanModal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why my second pop up "Basic2" is not working?
Here is a link to my pen:
http://codepen.io/wdcris/pen/szkIB

Seems very basic but i can't get it to work:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation on http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/:

> if you want more than one modal window on the same page, simply add the 'rel' attribute to
>   your triggers, and call the function by attribute, like so:

```
 $("a[rel*=leanModal]").leanModal();
```

You needed to add the `rel="leanModal"` attribute to your triggering links, and then binding the `.leanModal()` method to all links with that `rel="leanModal"` attribute.

Here's your example, simplified and fixed to work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqKrx

Hope this helps!

Comment: I checked the example but there is still no pop up on the second link.